# AFNetworking responseObject contains hex - how do I check for that?

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking

I am developing an app and an API that the app will talk to. I am pretty new to the developing an app side of thing!

Although the API should always return valid JSON, I want to handle the case where something goes wrong and it returns HTML (think DNS screwup).

I am using `AFNetworking` and `self.sessionmanager` is an `AFHTTPSessionManager`

Right now, my (very simplified) code says :

```
[self.sessionmanager GET:@"/app/api/v1/meetings/" parameters:params progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {

} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

    if ([responseObject containsObject:@"status"]) {
        // Do stuff  
    }
    else {
        // Do failure stuff
    }
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    // Do failure stuff
    return;
}];
```

The problem is that if I arrive at the success function with an HTML page instead of JSON, I get a `responseObject` that is hex and when I call `containsObject` I get an `NSInvalidArgumentException` with unrecognized selector sent to instance.

I tried putting a @try @catch block around the `containsObject` call, but it didn't seem to catch the exception.

How can I check whether `responseObject` is a valid object from a JSON response, in order to avoid the call to `containsObject` when required?

Comment: Check if `responseObject` is a `NSArray` or a `NSDictionary`, with `if ([responseObject isKindOfClass[NSArray class]]){}, etc.`. But it's strange, because if I remember correctly and if you use a `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` set to `AFJSONResponseSerializer` you should have the guarantee that the response is always JSON and so be nil (with an error, calling the failure block?) in case that the response is HTML.

Comment: @Larme - that did it, thanks. Not sure how I'm getting the response through though!